# Min and Max row numbers for specific data range (cell value dependent)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form that is submitted and using the date stamp generates the month name for each submission. what i need is a method to generate the minimum and maximum row number for each months data. so if January submissions start on row 1 and end on row 13, feb starts on 14 and ends on 30 march starts on 31 and ends on 36. i need a script that will tell me those specific row numbers. i will then use those as a seperate data range to generate a month overview of each line within that range.

below is what i have used so far but the results are not quite right:

```js
function findCell() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Votes');
  var lastRowSheet = sheet.getLastRow();
  var DataRange = "$B1:$B" + lastRowSheet.toString();
  var values = sheet.getRange(DataRange).getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  
  var test = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
  Logger.log("test - " + test);

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
    {
     var row = "";
     for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) 
      {     
      if (values[i][j] == "May") 
        {
        row = values[i][j+1];
        //Logger.log(row);
        Logger.log(i+1);
        }
      }    
    };

  for (var rowMinApr= 0; rowMinApr< values.length ; rowMinApr++ )
        {
        if (values[rowMinApr][0] == "April")
            {
            Logger.log("April min row - " + rowMinApr+1);
            break;
            }
        };
        
  for (var rowMaxApr= values.length -1 ; rowMaxApr>= 0 ; rowMaxApr-- )
        {
          if (values[rowMaxApr][0] == "April")
            {
            Logger.log("April max row - " + rowMaxApr+1);
            break;
            }
        };
        
  for (var rowMinMay= 0; rowMinMay< values.length ; rowMinMay++ )
        {
        if (values[rowMinMay][0] == "May")
            {
            Logger.log("Maymin row - " + rowMinMay+1);
            break;
            }
        };
        
  for (var rowMaxMay = values.length -1 ; rowMaxMay >= 0 ; rowMaxMay-- )
        {
          if (values[rowMaxMay][0] == "May")
            {
            Logger.log("May max row - " + rowMaxMay+1);
            break;
            }
        };
```

the log shows this:

[image]

as you can see where it lists the row numbers where the cell value is April it is fine, but when i try the code to find the minimum and maximum rown numbers applicable to the relevant cell content it throws up some prett random numbers. currently the cells that have April in are rows 2 to 15 and May is rows 16 to 27.

Comment: How far have you done?

Comment: This question presents as a _specification_, not a _programming issue_. To be a good question, it should show your effort (i.e. code) and describe a specific problem you have run into, what you've tried already, and what outcome you're expecting. Specific questions are more likely to yield solid answers.

Comment: Going on what Kriggs and Mogsdad said, please provide some code to show us what you've attempted and we can always provide some inputs to improve the solution.

Comment: edited above now with current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting one columns data.  The two dimensional array that is returned, will look like this:

```
[['monthName'],['monthName'],['monthName'],['monthName'],['monthName'],['monthName']]
```

There is only one element inside of each inner array.  So, the index number for each inner array is zero.  That will never change.

- Row one:  arrayName[i][0]
- Row two:  arrayName[i][0]
- Row three:  arrayName[i][0]
- Row four:  arrayName[i][0]

Note that the second index never changes, it's always zero.  Currently, you have an inner `for` loop.  You don't need a nested loop.  Why?  Because there is nothing to loop through in the inner array.  There is only one element.  It's always index zero.

Alternatively, you could convert the two dimensional array to a one dimensional array, since there is only one element in the inner array, and just use a one dimensional array.

Think about how you would do this "manually".  You could start on row one, look at the month, and see that it's month 'May'.  Okay, it's month 'May', I need to record that row 1 is in the 'May' category.  I'm not saying that this is the best strategy, I haven't thought through every possible solution.  But that's where I'd start.  So maybe have an array for the month of 'May', and record all the row numbers for 'May' in the 'May' array.  This strategy would need a separate array for every month.  So, you'd have an outer `for` loop for every month, then an inner `for` loop that would go through the `values` array, and do the matching.

So, you could have an array of all the months:

```
var theMonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr', etc];
```

Loop through the months:

```
for (var i=0;i<theMonths.length;i++) {
  var thisMonthToMatch = theMonths[i];

  //loop through all the values
  for (var j=0;j<values.length;j++) {

    var valueRetrieved = values[j][0];
    if (thisMonthToMatch === valueRetrieved) {
      //Record your info
    };

  };
};
```

Comment: perfect. i realised my mistake and in the log i was using +1 which was adding the number 1 to the row number, so it was in fact correct the whole time (well a row number out each time but that was easily fixed)

Answer (score 1):

```
function findCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Votes');
  var lastRowSheet = sheet.getLastRow();
  var DataRange = "$B2:$B" + lastRowSheet.toString();
  var months = sheet.getRange(DataRange).getValues();
  Logger.log(months[0][0] + " begins at row 2");
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < (months.length - 1); i++) {
    if(months[i][0] != months[i+1][0]) {
      Logger.log(months[i][0] + " ends at row " + (i+2));
      Logger.log(months[i+1][0] + " begins at row " + (i+3));
      }
    }
  Logger.log(months[i][0] + " ends at row " + (i+2));
}
```